# Публикация на google play

Tags: android, google-play

Опубликовал свое приложение для android в Google Play. Перед публикацией тестировал на своём смартфоне - все работало. Но после публикации Google Play говорить, что мой телефон не совместим с приложением. В чем причина?

Comment: в Manifest очевидно.

Comment: @igor Как говорится - хочешь получить хороший ответ, задай грамотный вопрос. Исправь свой вопрос, либо возможно он будет удален, как непонятный.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте [Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).
Именно его содержимое указывает плэй маркету, какие устройства будут совместимы с приложением, какие нет.

Подробная документация [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: Как я понимаю если бы в манифесте были бы разрешения несовместимые с моим телефоном то и тесты бы не запускались.

Comment: @igor Почему Вы так решили? Тесты запускаются на чём угодно, если в них не прописано посмотреть на манифест и не запускаться.

Comment: Даже релизная сборка ? Впрочем разрешения самые простые интернет чтение запись и состояния вайфая

Comment: Это тут вообще не при чем. Читайте внимательнее https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: Даже указанные типы экрана могут сыграть огромную роль в части показывать/не показывать приложение конкретному пользователю. Заявите только один экран - и будет у вас 1% от общего числа устройств совместимо (к примеру)